# html select attribute does not display value from database instead display the first option

Tags: javascript, html, css, grails

I got this problem with my code the select attribute that I got here does not display the value from the database instead it display the first option in the select field.
Here is the code:

```
<body>
   <g:form controller="customer" action="updateCustomer" class="updateCustomer" id="${cus.id}">
      <form>
         <div style="width:100%; padding-top: 50px; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; text-align: center">
            <div style = "height: 50vh; width: 70%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
               <div>
                  %{--                        Table for customer client--}%
                  <table class="table table-striped" id="table t1">
                     <colgroup>
                        <col>
                        <col>
                        <col>
                        <col>
                        <col>
                     </colgroup>
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th colspan="5" style="height: 40px;>
                           <h6 style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 40px;">
                              <g:link action="index" controller="customer">All Customers</g:link>
                              &nbsp;>>&nbsp;
                              <a href="#" onclick="goBack()">${cus.name}</a>&nbsp;>>&nbsp;EDIT
                           </h6>
                           </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <th colspan="5" style="height: 40px; text-align:center;background-color:lightseagreen">
                              <h6 style="font-weight: bold">EDIT CUSTOMER INFORMATION</h6>
                           </th>
                        </tr>
                

                        <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                           <td style = "width:30%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;"><span class="required">Status:</span></td>
                           <td style = "width:70%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;"> <g:select value = "${cus.status}" style = "width:90%" class="form-control" name="status" from="${["Active","Inactive"]}"></g:select></td>
                        </tr>


                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                  </table>
                  %{--                        End of table for customer client--}%
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
   </g:form>
```

In the <g:select> which is equivalent to select attribute in HTLM I already gave the value ${cus.status} but whenever I go into the EDIT customer pages instead of displaying that value in
the select menu instead it display the first value of the select which is Active.
In this example the user have Status of "Inactive"
[image]

But when I hit the EDIT button the status is 'Active'
[image]
Any ideas how i can fix this?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to replace my table row with this:

```
   <tr style="height: 70px;background-color: #f7fafd;">
                            <td style = "width:30%;font-weight: bold; text-align: right;padding-right: 20px;"><span class="required">Status:</span></td>
                            <td style = "width:70%;font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px;">
                                <select style = "width:90%"class = "form-control" name="status">
                                    <option disabled selected value> -- Select an option -- </option>
                                    <option value="selectValue" disabled selected hidden>${cus.status}</option>
                                    <option value="Active" select>Active</option>
                                    <option value="Inactive" select>Inactive</option>

                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the described misbehavior of the `g:select` tag.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-gsp/issues with an example that demonstrates the problem, we would be happy to investigate.  Thank you for the feedback.